# Allowing object B to obtain a reference to object A when object A references object B

Tags: c#, oop, reference, tree

Given a `treeNode parent` and a (soon to be) `treeNode child`, is there a way to, with out passing parent to child as a parameter, for child to obtain a reference to parent. Example

```
parent.AddChild(child); //allow child to update its parent as well
if(child.parent == parent) return true; //This needs to happen
```

So is there a hook i can implement which will allow `child` to hook onto `parent` when `parent` adds `child`

Note - i don't want to modify the `AddChild` method to allow child to be updated, i am interested in the reference passing which occurs and the possibility of this "behind-the-scene" reference passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no clean way.

You could achieve this by inspecting StackTrace, but I'd consider it an unreadable and errorprone hack.

Comment: Also consider what if the node could be part of two or more trees. I designed a large graph-like data structure where this could happen, and in my case it was important distinguishing between collections that own their members vs. just contain them. You might consider similar needs.

Comment: It ended up that the stacktrance was the better option. Kudos